# Numero de enlaces en un html y status

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en R y tengo que encontrar todos los enlaces en una página web, junto con su texto, y tengo que generar una tabla con cada enlace encontrado, indicando el texto que acompaña el enlace, y el número de veces que aparece un enlace con ese mismo objetivo.
Hasta ahora tengo todos los enlaces y su texto, pero al intentar contar el número de veces que aparece cada enlace, con la funcion table() o con la función count() de dplyr, hay enlaces que me desaparecen.
El código que llevo hecho hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
url <- "https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki"
html <- GET(url) 

content <- content(html, as = "text")
content

parsedHtml <- htmlParse(content, asText = TRUE)
parsedHtml

#2. Analizar el contenido de la web, buscando el título de la página

title <- xpathSApply(parsedHtml, "//title", xmlValue)
title

#3. Analizar el contenido de la web, buscando todos los enlaces, buscando el texto del enlace, así como la URL.

links_text <- xpathSApply(parsedHtml, "//a", xmlValue)
links_text

links_url   <- xpathSApply(parsedHtml, "//a", xmlGetAttr, 'href')  
links_url

valores_nulos_url <- sapply(links_url, is.null)
links_url[valores_nulos_url] <- NA
links_url <- unlist(links_url)
links_url

#4. Generar una tabla con cada enlace encontrado, indicando el texto que acompaña el enlace, y el número de veces que aparece un enlace con ese mismo objetivo.

df <- data.frame(Enlace = links_url, Texto = links_text)

t1 <- table(df$Enlace)
t1

numero_enlaces <- dplyr::count(df, df$Enlace)
numero_enlaces
```

¿Como podría contar el número de veces que aparece cada enlace?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El tema no es que desaparecen enlaces, ocurre que tanto `table`, como `count` son funciones de agrupación y hay en enlaces que se repiten, por lo que sin duda la agrupación arrojará menos filas que las originales.

De cualquier forma, entiendo que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  left_join(count(df, Enlace), by="Enlace")
```

Es decir, que cada fila tenga el número de veces que se repite el enlace de la misma, esto se logra contando y uniendo este resultado mediante un `left_join()`

Comment: Genial! es eso lo que buscaba, muchas gracias. El resultado de aplicar esa sentencia es ya un data frame con las tres columnas no? Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Carlos, si, efectivamente un `data.frame` o más bien un  `tibble` que casi lo mismo pero mejor